# How to find duplicated values in two columns between two dataframes and remove non-duplicates in R?

Tags: r

So let's say I have two dataframes that look like this

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A","B","F","G","B","B","A","G","G","F","A","A","A","B","F"),
                 code = c(1,2,2,3,3,1,2,2,1,1,3,2,2,1,1),
                 class =  c(2,4,5,5,2,3,2,5,1,2,4,5,3,2,1))

df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("G","F","C","F","B","A","F","C","A","B","A","B","C","A","G"),
                 code = c(1,2,2,3,3,1,2,2,1,1,3,2,2,1,1),
                 class =  c(2,4,5,5,2,3,2,5,1,2,4,5,3,2,1))
```

I want to check the duplicates in `df1$ID` and `df2$ID` and remove all the rows from `df2` if the IDs are not present in `df1` so the new dataframe would look like this:

```
df3 <- data.frame(ID = c("G","F","F","B","A","F","A","B","A","B","A","G"),
                 code = c(1,2,3,3,1,2,1,1,3,2,1,1),
                 class =  c(2,4,5,2,3,2,1,2,4,5,2,1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `%in%`:

```r
df2[df2$ID %in% df1$ID, ]

   ID code class
1   G    1     2
2   F    2     4
4   F    3     5
5   B    3     2
6   A    1     3
7   F    2     2
9   A    1     1
10  B    1     2
11  A    3     4
12  B    2     5
14  A    1     2
15  G    1     1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'intersect' function to tackle the issue.

```
common_ids <- intersect(df1$ID, df2$ID)
df3 <- df2[df2$ID %in% common_ids, ]

ID code class
1   G    1     2
2   F    2     4
4   F    3     5
5   B    3     2
6   A    1     3
7   F    2     2
9   A    1     1
10  B    1     2
11  A    3     4
12  B    2     5
14  A    1     2
15  G    1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to throw `semi_join` in.

```
library(tidyverse)
df_test <- df2 |> semi_join(df1, by = "ID")
all.equal(df3, df_test)
#> [1] TRUE
```